# SVN - How to use external diff3 for binary files?

Tags: svn, diff3

I have some external mydiff3.exe, working with text and binary files.

My svn command line is

```
svn.exe update my_work_copy_path --diff3-cmd mydiff3.exe
```

This work well for text files (svn call mydiff3.exe for each conflicted files through update process), but for binary files svn skip the mydiff3.exe and show the internal commandline menu.

**How to tell to svn to accept *--diff3-cmd mydiff3.exe* for binary files?**

RTFM ([diff3-cmd](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.diff3_cmd) and [External Tools](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) from svn red-book) doesn't help.

**UPD**:
There is a mention that the behavior depends on mime-type - but it is not clear where to configure it.

Comment: I've post the same question into the subversion mail group http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201508.mbox/browser, but there is no answer